# SSL_shutdown not understandable between man page and program behavior

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I try to write function to handle SSL shutdown. Below is part of the server code, where I use non-block mode.

```
   int r = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
   if (r == 1)
   {
      return Success;
   }

   // according to man/SSL_shutdown, 0 means "in progress"
   if (r == 0)
   {
      switch ((r = SSL_get_error(ssl, r)))
      {
         case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            std::cout << "shutdown want read" << std::endl;
            ...
            return ...;

         case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            std::cout << "shutdown want write" << std::endl;
            ...
            return ...;

         default:
            std::cout << r << " " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            ...
            return ...;
      }
   }
```

This is part of the client code, where I use blocking mode. According to man, I should call it twice.

```
   if (SSL_shutdown(ssl) == 0)
   {
      if (SSL_shutdown(ssl) != 1)
      {
         report_error_and_exit("SSL_shutdown");
      }
   }
```

In the server, the SSL_shutdown returns 0. According to man page, then SSL_get_error should return either SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.

Quote: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_shutdown.html

> If the underlying BIO is nonblocking and the shutdown process is not yet complete (for example, because a close_notify alert message has not yet been received from the peer, or because a close_notify alert message needs to be sent but would currently block), SSL_shutdown() returns 0 to indicate that the shutdown process is still ongoing; in this case, a call to SSL_get_error(3) will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE.

However, I get print from default with r = 5 (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL). In such case, the man says should check errno, but strerror returns "Success". Everything is so confusing.

Comment: _This is part of the client code, where I use blocking mode. According to man, I should call `SSL_shutdown` twice._  Where are you getting that from?  I don't see it in the [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_shutdown.html).  FWIW, I only call it once, and everything is working fine.  Or are you using a NON-blocking socket?  then, you *might* need to jump through some hoops, as the passage you quote makes clear.  But non-blocking sockets and OpenSSL are not exactly a marriage made in heaven, so I don't use them.  Instead, I do any asynchronous operations in a sub-thread.

Comment: @PaulSanders, It is mentioned in man, for blocking mode should call twice "Shutdown Lifecycle
Regardless of whether a shutdown was initiated locally or by the peer, if the underlying BIO is blocking, a call to SSL_shutdown() will return firstly once a close_notify alert message is written to the peer (returning 0), and upon a second and subsequent call, once a corresponding message is received from the peer (returning 1 and completing the shutdown process). Calls to SSL_shutdown() with a blocking underlying BIO will also return if an error occurs."

Comment: @PaulSanders, I take your comment to switch the shutdown part of the server to blocking mode, and it goes through.

Comment: _It is mentioned in man_ I think the documentation I linked to might be more reliable.

Comment: @PaulSanders, It could be, I randomly land in https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_shutdown.html.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I saw the wrong name on the post.  I meant to direct that comment to the OP.

Comment: @user180574 did you miss this part of the doc you linked to? "*Unlike most other functions, **returning 0 does not indicate an error. SSL_get_error(3) should not be called**; it may misleadingly indicate an error even though no error occurred.*" Even the section you quoted from has more information you omitted, basically telling you that when the 1st `SSL_shutdown()` returns 0, use `SSL_read()` in a loop before calling the 2nd `SSL_shutdown()`, and to call `SSL_get_error()` only in relation to `SSL_read()`, not to `SSL_shutdown()`.

Comment: @PaulSanders: In your docs, it says *...After SSL_shutdown() returned 0, it is possible to call SSL_shutdown() again to wait for the peer's close_notify alert...*

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk So it does, thank you.  I think I've worked this out now (found some better docs), posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I can answer this now, because I found some better documentation (good old Linux):

https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_shutdown

So, quoting from there:

> The shutdown procedure consists of 2 steps: the sending of the "close notify" shutdown alert and the reception of the peer's "close notify" shutdown alert.
>
> According to the TLS standard, it is acceptable for an application to only send its shutdown alert and then close the underlying connection without waiting for the peer's response (this way resources can be saved, as the process can already terminate or serve another connection). When the underlying connection shall be used for more communications, the complete shutdown procedure (bidirectional "close notify" alerts) must be performed, so that the peers stay synchronized.

So SSL_shutdown is indeed a two-step process.  It then goes on to say (commentary and minor clarifying edits mine):

> When the application is the first party to send the "close notify" alert [as, I assume, is the case here], `SSL_shutdown()` will only send the alert and then set the `SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN` flag (so that the session is considered good and will be kept in cache).
>
> `SSL_shutdown()` will then return with `0`. If a unidirectional shutdown is enough (i.e. the underlying connection shall be closed anyway), this first call to `SSL_shutdown()` is sufficient
>
> In order to complete the bidirectional shutdown handshake, `SSL_shutdown()` must be called again. The second call will make `SSL_shutdown()` wait for the peer's "close notify" shutdown alert. On success, the second call to `SSL_shutdown()` will return with `1`.

In other words, if you're planning to dispose of `ssl` (in the code as posted), then calling `SSL_shutdown` once is sufficient (and this is what I do).  OTOH, if you plan to use `ssl` again, you might have to call it twice.

There's some other bumph but what it boils down to is that if `SSL_shutdown` returns `0`, and you want to reuse `ssl`, then you have to call it again.  If it returns `1`, you don't (regardless of your future plans for `ssl`).

Finally, it says this:

> If the underlying BIO is blocking, `SSL_shutdown()` will only return once the handshake step has been finished or an error occurred.

Which I take to mean that, for blocking sockets, you ever need to call it once.  For non-blocking sockets, you need to take a bit more care.  But, my reading of the docs tells me that the most robust way to code this (if you plan to reuse `ssl`) would be:

```
int rc = SSL_shutdown (ssl);
if (rc == 0)
    rc = SSL_shutdown (ssl);
...
```

Personally, I don't use non-blocking sockets with OpenSSL anyway, there are too many gotchas.  Instead, I spin up a thread, but I can see for a server application that that might not be acceptable.  And sorry I didn't read your question properly first time round, OP.

Happy to be corrected by wiser heads on any of the above.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, which helps a lot!